# How correctly to wrap http request in the processor of routes express and to deduce the answer in HTML?

Tags: node.js, express, request

There is a form where by pressing the button a text file should be unloaded, using the request library I send a request to another server and output the text file to the console. Well, actually the question itself, but how do I output the result in the html template, and not in the console. The HTTP request itself looks like this:

```
var request = require('request');
request.get('http://177.77.45.99:8081/gall/cesar.txt',function(error, 
response, 
body){
console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); 
console.log('body:', body);
});
```

How do I wrap this in the handler "router.get ('/ roumer', function (req, res)" and output for example in the ejs template at the click of a button in textarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your code in the router function.

**Option 1 - Return plain text**
This code returns txt file as plain text;

```
router.get('/ roumer', function (req, res) {
   var request = require('request');
   request.get('http://177.77.45.99:8081/gall/cesar.txt', function (error,response,body) {
    console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
    console.log('body:', body);

    res.end(body)

   });
});
```

**Option 2 - Use html render engine**

And if you want to return html page, you can use jade template to render html file. It will something like that. resultPage.jade is your file in views/ folder. You can do some research jade.

```
router.get('/ roumer', function (req, res) {
    var request = require('request');
    request.get('http://177.77.45.99:8081/gall/cesar.txt', function (error,response,body) {
       console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
       console.log('body:', body);
       res.render('resultPage.jade', {
        responseTextBody : body
       } )
    });
});
```

**Option 3 - Create and return html in sipmliest way**

If you dont want to jade/pug or another render engine and keep it super simple, you can simply return plan text with html tags. You can simply copy this code.

```
router.get('/ roumer', function (req, res) {
  var request = require('request');
  request.get('http://177.77.45.99:8081/gall/cesar.txt', function (error,response,body) {
      console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
      console.log('body:', body);

      let htmlBody = "<!DOCTYPE html>< html ><body><p> " + body + "</p></body></html >"

      res.end( htmlBody )
  });
});
```

**Bonus**

By the way, there is a whitespace between / and r chars in your code. It may be mistake, please check it.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, you have helped me a lot, if you do not mind, I would like to ask you more, for example, there is a template with different forms, and in one it is necessary to display this text file in the textarea by clicking on the button, how can I do that.